# IIS Express crash

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

all, I have an issue with a web application when debug running (F5) in the visual studio 2013. The web app can be loaded, And I can see the startup page of it . But after it run for a while . Windows 7 will pop up an error message saying "IIS Worker Process has stopped working.", then it will prompt me to Debug or Close program. And I found it crashed for some reasons.

[image]

```
Problem signature:
      Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
      Application Name: iisexpress.exe
      Application Version:  8.0.8418.0
      Application Timestamp:    4fbaa9e8
      Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
      Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17725
      Fault Module Timestamp:   4ec49b8f
      Exception Code:   c0000005
      Exception Offset: 000222b2
      OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
      Locale ID:    1033
      Additional Information 1: 957c
      Additional Information 2: 957c29dfdb991ec81e38235721c38e4b
      Additional Information 3: ccd2
      Additional Information 4: ccd256cc19bebfc9147c237d7b853273
```

Of course, I've tried to Debug it, but VS just says the IIS Express can not be debugged.

[image]

I also followed the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053708/how-to-debug-w3wp-exe-process-was-terminated-due-to-a-stack-overflow-works-on) and tried to get the crush dump file to figure out what root reason cause the crash. But didn't found any dump file for IIS Express. Please help me out . Thanks.

BTW . I had tried to deploy the web app to IIS 7. and It works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is a windows azure cloud service. If I set the azure project as start up project instead of the web role. It works fine. I hope it is helpful if you encounter the same problem. thanks.