# Error with clr.dll file - website taking up all CPU

Tags: asp.net, iis, dll

One of my websites has been running fine for the last 3-4 years and all of a sudden it's stopped working.

I keep getting 504 errors or 502 errors and in some browsers it just hangs for ages and this is taking up all the CPU on the server making the rest of the sites perform really slow.

Nothing has changed in the code for at least a year so i'm pretty certain that its not a code problem but I have absolutely no idea of what it could be.

The server says that it is something to do with `clr.dll` but I have no idea what that is.

My background is jus .Net coding I have little knowledge of IIS.

I am able to solve the problem by changing the value of my Session to something different but that would mean changing hundreds of pages throughout the website so I'm reluctant to do this.

Does anybody have any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: Maybe your provider change the pool settings and your app make constantly recycles. Or can not write to some database for any reason, or ca not connect to the database for any reason. Sounds that your provider broke it.

Comment: in any case sounds that your provider make an update that is not working. Time to change your provider.

Comment: @Aristos the problem is that it also occurs locally :/

Comment: then read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044752/how-do-i-crash-the-app-pool/3045137#3045137

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem in the end.

There was a page that was trying to loop through something when there wasn't anything to loop through.

Instead of giving me an ASP error it just broke the website and gave 504 errors.

Slightly misleading information but I got there in the end!

Answer (score 0):

`clr.dll` is just the way the .NET code is called from windows, so it only indicates the problem is somewhere in the .NET code. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/31705019/8479.

To figure out what's actually going on you're best to do the normal app debugging things:

- look at the application logs
- check the event viewer
- use Process Explorer to see what it's doing
- use Process Monitor to really see what's happening on the machine
- use other monitoring tools as appropriate for your app, e.g. SQL Profiler for database work.