# Stack overflow cause

Tags: asp.net, event-log

I am getting the following error in Event Viewer->

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bd0eb 
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.269, time stamp: 0x4ee9d6e1 
Exception code: 0xc00000fd 
Fault offset: 0x00000000003b9699 
Faulting process id: 0x27bc 
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd8b60efe44b8a 
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe 
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll 
Report Id: bf405bd2-f80c-11e1-8138-9ffa688390c1
```

How to know the cause for this?
Windows error reporting is ON, but still there is no report.

Comment: This app has raised the limit of RAM dedicated to the pool, you can use CRL profiler and observe how is growing the memory consumption and detect blottlenecks. CLR profiler is installed with .NET SDK in your system

Comment: see this similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044752/how-do-i-crash-the-app-pool/3045137#3045137

Answer (score 3):

0x c00000fd is a stack overflow exception as listed in your question title.
w3wp.exe means it could be in your application.

You may have an unlimited recursion in your code.