# Cpu spikes in windows 2003 w3wp.exe

Tags: asp.net, .net, garbage-collection

We are having application crashes in a large .net web app due to cpu spikes on windows 2003. I have collected the userdump using ms debug diagnostic tool to investigate the issue. I can see the following in the analysis summary

> Warning The following threads in w3wp.exe_*TKN2011*_PID_*285884*_Date__12_25_2013__Time_06_00_59PM_*810*_Manual Dump.dmp are waiting for .net garbage collection to finish. Thread 45 triggered the garbage collection.The gargage collector thread wont start doing its work till the time the threads which have pre-emptive GC disabled have finished executing. The following threads have pre-emptive GC disabled 40,

( 16 30 31 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 41 42 43 46 )

25.93% of threads blocked

> Warning The following threads in w3wp.exe_*TKN2011*_PID_*285884*_Date__12_25_2013__Time_06_00_59PM_*810*_Manual Dump.dmp are making an HttpWebRequest and waiting on the remote server to respond

These threads are also waiting on data to be returned from another server via WinSock.

The call to WinSock originated from 0x029ea1c3 and is destined for port 80 at IP address xx.xxx.105.174

( 44 )

1.85% of threads blocked

Also I can see in the report

> Top 5 Threads by CPU time
>   Note - Times include both user mode and kernel mode for each thread Thread ID: 43     Total CPU Time: 00:15:13.671     Entry Point for Thread: mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc 
>   Thread ID: 42     Total CPU Time: 00:14:06.280     Entry Point for Thread: mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc 
>   Thread ID: 41     Total CPU Time: 00:13:58.046     Entry Point for Thread: mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc 
>   Thread ID: 46     Total CPU Time: 00:13:11.781     Entry Point for Thread: mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc 
>   Thread ID: 40     Total CPU Time: 00:13:04.702     Entry Point for Thread: mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc

There is a lot in this analysis report. Any ideas how shall i go about troubleshooting this? thanks

Comment: See this answer for a tip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044752/how-do-i-crash-the-app-pool/3045137#3045137

Comment: Thanks Aristos. From the information above, shall I look into the thread 45?