# Websitepanel Application pool crashes

Tags: asp.net, iis, server

I am running on window 2012 R2 OS with IIS role installed on it. I have also installed websitepanel and add the websitepanel as a site in IIS.

I have created 3 Application pools for individual website :-

(1) Websitepanel Portal :- To run websitepanel.
(2) Websitepanel Enterprise Server 
(3) Websitepanel Server

I have bind the application pool with all 3 websites. The problem is whenever i am going to start the websitpanel, the application pool of websitepanel crashes.

The browser gives the following error.

Service unavailable

Also IIS admin service not going to start. Asking me to search Event log.

I have checked my server usage and it is normal. I have 3 GB RAM and 35 GB diskspace on my server.

Can anyone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

`Asking me to search Event log`

Ok this is the answer here, search your `event log` on the server, and there you find a line that say and have the report of the error. Base on that report you can find your problem.

Relative answers:
[How do I crash the App Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044752/how-do-i-crash-the-app-pool/3045137#3045137)
[Deploying website: 500 - Internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884)

### Note

Your server running under almost the minimum ram **and below the minimum hard disk** !

[System Requirements for Windows Server 2012 R2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn383626(v=ws.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Herrick,

I assume that, you owned server and have access to remote desktop OR IIS. You can try with following options to resolve your problelm:

1) Please enable 32 bit mode for all three application pools for WebsitePanel.
2) Increase private memory for application pools.
3) If you are running with fresh server then have a try with reinstallation of this application again.

Regards,