# How to crash an ASP.NET/Core application for all users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to test logging of critical errors in an ASP.NET/ASP.NET-Core application. 

Now to test this, I need to produce an error that crashes the application for all users.

Something like

```
FATAL ERROR : Signal Received: SIGSEGV (11)
```

I can certainly produce a YSOD on a http-request with ease, but how to artificially produce an error that crashes the entire application, that is to say for all users ?

Comment: Maybe some of these will work: [How do I crash the App Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3044752/1316573)

Comment: Cause an OOM exception.

Comment: I'd guess that an OOM or StackOverflow exception would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Any stackoverflowing bug should do the trick. 
Example:

```
public class StackOverflower
{
    private string m_MyText;

    public string MyText
    {
        get { return MyText; }
        set { this.m_MyText = value; }
    }
}


class Program
{
    [System.STAThread()]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new StackOverflower();
        System.Console.WriteLine(foo.MyText);
    }
}
```